# import sap bw over hana via sqoop

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, hana, sap-bw

Currently I am trying to import a sap hana table with sqoop. Here I encounter the problem that both the table names and the column names contain forward slashes "/".

For the table names I can use the query option and escaping the table name as workaround. But if I want to import the table with different mappers, I want to use the -m option in combination with --split-by. Here I can't specify "/" in the column name without getting the following error.

```
20/06/26 08:05:02 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.JDBCDriverException: SAP DBTech JDBC: [257] (at 12): sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "/": line 1 col 12 (at pos 12)
```

The query that is getting generated by sqoop looks like that

```
SELECT MIN(/SOMETHING/KEY_COLUMN), MAX(/SOMETHING/KEY_COLUMN) FROM (select * from SCHEMA."/SOMETHING/TABLE_NAME") AS t1
```

The statement:

```
sqoop import -D org.apache.sqoop.splitter.allow_text_splitter=true \
--driver com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver \
--connect jdbc:sap://alias:port/ \
--split-by "/SOMETHING/KEY_COLUMN" \
--target-dir /target-dir \
--delete-target-dir \
--query "select * from SCHEMA.\"/SOMETHING/TABLE_NAME\" where 1=1 AND \$CONDITIONS" \
--as-parquetfile \
--username username \
--password pw \
--num-mappers 4 \
--verbose
```

How can I escape the --split-by column correctly?

Comment: Have checked using ` (backtick)?

Comment: i tried it, but it resolves in an empty field ` /SOMETHING/KEY_COLUMN ` -> ""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked with using

> --split - by "("/SOMETHING/KEY_COLUMN")"\

```js
sqoop
import -D org.apache.sqoop.splitter.allow_text_splitter = true\
  --driver com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver\
  --connect jdbc: sap: //alias:port/ \
  --split - by "(\"/SOMETHING/KEY_COLUMN\")"\
  --target - dir / target - dir\
  --delete - target - dir\
  --query "select * from SCHEMA.\"/SOMETHING/TABLE_NAME\" where 1=1 AND \$CONDITIONS"\
  --as - parquetfile\
  --username username\
  --password pw\
  --num - mappers 4\
  --verbose
```